# IOUtils.copy() in tcp

Tags: java, sockets, apache-commons-io

I am making a program that sends a file over TCP from the client to server via the `IOUtils` by copying the fileinputstream to the outputstream in the client and copying the input stream to fileoutputstream in the server. But for this to work, I have to close the streams at the end of the file transfer and after that, I cannot send another file. So is there a way to send multiple files using this method?

Comment: I don't understand, if your are reading a new file then the inputstream will be different and unless you are appending two files the outputstream will also be different won't they?

Comment: If you're sending a file, use HTTP. That's what it's designed for. It deals with all the underlying TCP streams for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common methods for sending multiple messages in one connection are

- sending the length of the message (here: file size), so the remote party knows when to stop reading by counting bytes
- signalling the end of data by sending a special string that the file cannot contain

You probably are better off with the first one.

Alternatively you could consider using zip file input and output streams; they can contain several independent file entries

Comment: Hi thank you for replying quickly. I am a bit new to java. So could you elaborate on how I can stop the reading of bytes? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? You stop reading by exiting the loop where you read.